# python : import UiDevices, UiObject and UiSelector from Uiautomator

Tags: android, python

How to import the java classes in a python script?

I tried:

> from uiautomator import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject

and it returns error as:

> from uiautomator import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject
>                                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use following code

```
from uiautomator import Device, Selector, AutomatorDeviceUiObject
```

If these modules not exactly what you need, then use

```
import uiautomator as ui
dir(ui)
```

to select required modules

Comment: Hello There, Although the former doesn't return any error, it neither serves my purpose :( That is it doesn' return the list of required modules.

Comment: Please explain again. My code doesn't fit your purpose? These modules are not what you search for? or `dir()` function doesn't returns the list?

Comment: When I execute the below code

import uiautomator as ui
dir(ui)

I expect  to see an output listing the modules, Unfortunately I do not any output, but neither is there any error

It just returns to command prompt.

Comment: let me clarify: you should run provided code in python shell , not in command prompt. you can also try `print(dir(ui))` (for Python3) or `print dir(ui)` (for Python2). This should return list